# Pandas - Filling Missing values from list in Groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame with multiple category fields. I would like to fill the missing values in a column from other available list of values and this missing value should follow the group order.

This number list is not fixed. It will change based on 'Code B' and 'Code A'. We can't fix the number list.

```
| Code A | Code B | Hour | number | number list |
| ------ | ------ | ---- | ------ | ----------- |
| ABC    | ABC.1A | 2    | A      | [A,B,C,D,E] |
| ABC    | ABC.1A | 2    | NaN    | [A,B,C,D,E] |
| ABC    | ABC.1A | 2    | NaN    | [A,B,C,D,E] |
| ABC    | ABC.1A | 2    | B      | [A,B,C,D,E] |
| ABC    | ABC.1A | 2    | NaN    | [A,B,C,D,E] |
| ABC    | ABC.2B | 4    | NaN    | [AB,BD,CF,DH,EK] |
| ABC    | ABC.2B | 4    | CF     | [AB,BD,CF,DH,EK] |
| ABC    | ABC.2B | 4    | Nan    | [AB,BD,CF,DH,EK] |
| ABC    | ABC.2B | 4    | NaN    | [AB,BD,CF,DH,EK] |
| ABC    | ABC.2B | 4    | AB     | [AB,BD,CF,DH,EK] |
```

I would like to fill the missing value based on Hour group and want below data frame.

```
| Code A | Code B | Hour | number | number list |
| ------ | ------ | ---- | ------ | ----------  |
| ABC    | ABC.1A | 2    | A      | [A,B,C,D,E] |
| ABC    | ABC.1A | 2    | C      | [A,B,C,D,E] |
| ABC    | ABC.1A | 2    | D      | [A,B,C,D,E] |
| ABC    | ABC.1A | 2    | B      | [A,B,C,D,E] |
| ABC    | ABC.1A | 2    | E      | [A,B,C,D,E] |
| ABC    | ABC.2B | 4    | DH     | [AB,BD,CF,DH,EK] |
| ABC    | ABC.2B | 4    | CF     | [AB,BD,CF,DH,EK] |
| ABC    | ABC.2B | 4    | BD     | [AB,BD,CF,DH,EK] |
| ABC    | ABC.2B | 4    | EK     | [AB,BD,CF,DH,EK] |
| ABC    | ABC.2B | 4    | AB     | [AB,BD,CF,DH,EK] |
```

Not able to figure out how to keep the running list and pop out a number if available in 'number' column otherwise put the number. This also needs to be in an hour (and other two Code A, Code B) groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) and a generator:

```
def cust_fill(g, to_fill='number', ref='number list'):
    existing = set(g[to_fill].dropna())
    values = (v for v in df[ref].iloc[0] if v not in existing)
    return pd.Series([next(values, None) if pd.isna(value) else value
                      for value in g[to_fill]], index=g.index)

df['number'] = df.groupby(['Code A', 'Code B'], group_keys=False).apply(cust_fill)
```

Output:

```
  Code A  Code B  Hour number      number list
0    ABC  ABC.1A     2      A  [A, B, C, D, E]
1    ABC  ABC.1A     2      C  [A, B, C, D, E]
2    ABC  ABC.1A     2      D  [A, B, C, D, E]
3    ABC  ABC.1A     2      B  [A, B, C, D, E]
4    ABC  ABC.1A     2      E  [A, B, C, D, E]
5    ABC  ABC.2B     4      D  [A, B, C, D, E]
6    ABC  ABC.2B     4      C  [A, B, C, D, E]
7    ABC  ABC.2B     4      B  [A, B, C, D, E]
8    ABC  ABC.2B     4      E  [A, B, C, D, E]
9    ABC  ABC.2B     4      A  [A, B, C, D, E]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function to each group. In the function you can track current free symbols and use them to fill NaNs one by one:

```
import copy

def fill_na_with_pattern(group, pattern=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]):
    _, free_elements = copy.deepcopy(list(pattern.items())[0])
    for element in group:
        if element is not None and not pd.isna(element):
            free_elements.remove(element)
    
    pattern_idx = 0
    for i, element in group.items():
        if element is None or pd.isna(element):
            group[i] = free_elements[pattern_idx]
            pattern_idx += 1

    return group

df["filled_number"] = df \
    .groupby("CodeB", group_keys=False) \
    .apply(lambda group: fill_na_with_pattern(group["number"], group["number_list"]))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  CodeA   CodeB Hour number           number_list filled_number
0   ABC  ABC.1A    2      A       [A, B, C, D, E]             A
1   ABC  ABC.1A    2    NaN       [A, B, C, D, E]             C
2   ABC  ABC.1A    2    NaN       [A, B, C, D, E]             D
3   ABC  ABC.1A    2      B       [A, B, C, D, E]             B
4   ABC  ABC.1A    2    NaN       [A, B, C, D, E]             E
5   ABC  ABC.2B    4     DH  [AB, BD, CF, DH, EK]            DH
6   ABC  ABC.2B    4     CF  [AB, BD, CF, DH, EK]            CF
7   ABC  ABC.2B    4    NaN  [AB, BD, CF, DH, EK]            BD
8   ABC  ABC.2B    4    NaN  [AB, BD, CF, DH, EK]            EK
9   ABC  ABC.2B    4     AB  [AB, BD, CF, DH, EK]            AB
```

Edit: support separate patterns for each group.

Comment: Pattern can't be fixed. It will change based on 'CodeA' and 'CodeB'. Edited the question.

Comment: Fair enough! I've updated my answer to support that.